# Proof of Gray code

Tags: coding-theory

> Prove that for every $n \in \mathbb N$ with $n \geq 1$ a $1$-step binary code $C_n$ for the inteval $[0, 2^n −1]$ with code words of length $n$ exists.

I have to prove it using induction.

Comment: Welcome to SE. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Tried to find a function for the 1 step binary. Just struggled to define a function for that came to the point of 0 0, 0 1, 1 0 , 1 1. is 0 and 1 with added 0 and 1. And frustrating don't know if it's kind of a right way to solve the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given an $n$ bit code, an $n+1$ bit code consists of all the strings prefixed with a $0$ and all the strings prefixed with $1$.  Start with the code with the $0$ prefix, which gets you half way there. All the rest start with $1$, so the first code with $1$ has to match on all of he other bits. Going from the last to the first you will have a change in the first bit, so again all the others have to match. Can you see how to construct it?

Comment: So the n+1 Code is 2 times the n code with 1 and 0 added in front and these put together are the gray code. But how do i write down this in a mathematical proof with induction.

Comment: You have to reverse the order of the second half to make it work. You have to explain that there is only one bit changed at each point

Comment: For example, a two bit code is $00,01,11,10$.  Put a zero in front of each, then put a one in front in reverse order and you get $000,001,011,010,110,111,101,100$ which works.  You need to show this process always works.